# How do you describe a person's actions which don't demonstrate creativity?

Tags: word-request

'Uningenious' doesn't seem to be a common word. What could I use instead? 'Unimaginative', I guess? What else? How do you describe a person's actions which don't demonstrate creativity, the ability to solve problems using clever, as opposed to the most obvious, methods?

Comment: "Uncreative" is a legitimate word and literally means "lacks creativity."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say that a person always finds ***unoriginal*** or ***unclever*** solutions. You could also describe them as ***predictable*** or ***unskilled***.

You can always look up more [antonyms](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-opposite-of/ingenious.html) of *ingenious*.

Personally I like ***[uninventive](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/uninventive.html)***:

> Lacking in creativity, originality or imagination

Comment: I would like to go without un-words. Something that has connotations of excessive straightforwardness, maybe even stupidity

Answer (score 0):

Trite, hackneyed, unoriginal, cliche, platitudinous, and uninspired all work.